# jQuery – Hide menu/sidebar when click in the body area

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, css-transitions, sidebar

I'm very new to jQuery and coding in general and have been trying to get this sidebar to work. When you click on the INFO link a sidebar opens up. As of right now you can only close the sidebar by clicking on the X in the corner, but I want to also be able to close the sidebar when you click in the body area (but not when you click in the sidebar area). I got this to work sort of, but then I wasn't able to open any of my links to view my projects (only the second project, Frankenstein eBook, has a functioning link as of now).

Also, why are you able to click on the whole width of the line the X is on instead of just the X to close the sidebar?

I've seen a lot of similar problems on here but could never quite match it up to mine specifically. Any help would be awesome, and i Thank you!

Here is my site: [Josh Diaz Portfolio](http://educ.jmu.edu/~diazjr/portfolio_website/index.html)

And here is a JSFiddle: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/diazjr/2Rm8h/)

My HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
<!--Sidebar-->
<!--Info Panel-->
<div class="infoPanel">
    <nav class="closeBtn">  <a href="#">X</a>

    </nav>
    <div class="infoText">
            <h2>infoPanel</h2>

        <p>Copy goes here.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<section class="sidebar">
    <div class="sidebarNav">
        <nav>   <a class="infoLink" href="#">INFO</a>

        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <section class="projects">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <ul class="grid">
                    <li>    <a href="prj.html">
                    <div class="caption"><span>Image Go Here</span></div>
                    <img src="http://educ.jmu.edu/~diazjr/portfolio_website/images/coming_soon.jpg" />
                </a>

                    </li>
                    <li>    <a href="prj.html">
                    <div class="caption"><span>Image Go Here</span></div>
                    <img src="http://educ.jmu.edu/~diazjr/portfolio_website/images/coming_soon.jpg" />
                </a>

                    </li>
                    <li>    <a href="prj.html">
                    <div class="caption"><span>Images Go Here</span></div>
                    <img src="http://educ.jmu.edu/~diazjr/portfolio_website/images/coming_soon.jpg" />
                </a>

                    </li>
                    <li>    <a href="prj.html">
                    <div class="caption"><span>Image Go Here</span></div>
                    <img src="http://educ.jmu.edu/~diazjr/portfolio_website/images/coming_soon.jpg" />
                </a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</section>
```

My JS:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {

        var menu = "close";

        $('.infoLink').click(function () {

            if (menu == "close") {
                $('.infoPanel').css('-webkit-transform', 'translate(0,0)');
                menu = "open";
            } else {
                $('.infoPanel').css('-webkit-transform', 'translate(100%,0)');
                menu = "close";
            }
        });

        $('.closeBtn').click(function () {

            if (menu == "close") {
                $('.infoPanel').css('-webkit-transform', 'translate(0,0)');
                menu = "open";
            } else {
                $('.infoPanel').css('-webkit-transform', 'translate(100%,0)');
                menu = "close";
            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far. Include a working fiddle as well if you can.

Comment: I added a jsfiddle. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Also, why are you able to click on the whole width of the line the X is on instead of just the X to close the sidebar?

Because `$('.closeBtn')` is referring to `div` and not the link, use `$('.closeBtn a')` instead.

Anyway, heres another Quick and dirty way ( needs a bit of refactoring ) but the idea is there. I'll add comments to this if it works for you: http://jsfiddle.net/Varinder/RfFSv/

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var menu = "close";            
        var $infoLink = $(".infoLink");
        var $infoPanel = $(".infoPanel");
        var $closeButton = $(".closeBtn a");
        var $document = $(document);

        $infoLink.on("click.nav",function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            sidebar("open");
        });

        $closeButton.on("click.nav",function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            sidebar("close");
        });

        $document.on("click.nav", function(e) {
            if ( !$infoPanel.is(e.target) && $infoPanel.has(e.target).length === 0 ) {
                 sidebar("close");
            }
        });

        function sidebar(action) {
            if (action == "open") {
                $('.infoPanel').css('-webkit-transform', 'translate(0,0)');
                menu = "open";
            } else if (action == "close") {
                console.log("stuff");
                $('.infoPanel').css('-webkit-transform', 'translate(100%,0)');
                menu = "close";
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you so much. Comments would be wonderful. I've spent way too much time trying to figure this out, and I knew it was something simple but I just couldn't quite get it. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

Your HTML

```
<body>
   <div id="content"></div>
   <div id="sidebar"></div>
</body>
```

And your JS

```
$('body').click(function(){
   $('#sidebar').hide(); //hide sidebar when body is clicked
});

$('#sidebar').click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation(); //this call will cancel the execution bubble
});
```

I hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I'll test it out as soon as I can!

Comment: I added the JS and it didn't work. Do I need to rearrange my html to match what you listed?